# Calculating Time Complexity.. Need help coming up with the end result

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

Studying for a midterm tomorrow, and these time complexities are something I struggle with.  I'm going over the simple examples in the book and for this example

**Exchange Sort**

```
void exchangesort (int n, keytype S[])
{
  index i, j;
  for(i=1; i<=n-1; i++)
    for(j=i+1; j<=n; j++)
      if(S[j] < S[i])
        exchange S[i] and S[j];
}
```

For the "Every-Case Time Complexity" of this Exchange sort, I understand the part that we pretty much analyze the `j` for-loop, because it has the basic operation (the exchange). And so if you list out the total number of passes, it's given by:

```
T(n) = (n-1) + (n-2) + (n-3) + ... + 1 = (n-1)n/2
```

Now my question is... where does the 1 come from?  I thought it was `n-1 + n-2 +... + n`.

Furthermore, what I really don't understand is how to come up with the `(n-1)n/2`.
That's obviously what I have to come up with in the midterm, and by looking at that, `(n-1)n/2` doesn't come intuitively...  I understand how to come up with the `T(n) = (n-1) + (n-2)` etc., I think...

Can someone explain this to me in laymen's terms so I can come up with an answer like this for my midterm tomorrow?

Comment: I don remember very well the details. But notice that in the **worst** case, each loop would do **n** passes. So, you have 2 **nested** loops. That is why you have the (n)(n). I hope that others stackoverflowers gve you the precise answer.

Answer (score 4):

In the inner loop, `j` runs from `i+1` to `n`, that is, through `n-i` values. So altogether, there are

```
sum_{i = 1 to n-1} (n-i)
```

steps, `(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + (n - (n-1)) = (n-1) + (n-2) + ... . 1`.

Now, for the sum of the first `k` positive integers, there is a closed formula, it's

```
k*(k+1)/2
```

Here, `k = n-1`.

To work out the formula for the sum of the first `k` positive integers, there are several nice ways, as mentioned in [robert king's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9200533/1011995). Allegedly, Gauss worked it out in the first way when he was five years old and the teacher gave the pupils the task to calculate the sum of the integers from 1 to 100 in the hope of having a few quiet minutes. It's better to see if arranged thus:

```
  1   +   2   + ... + (n-1) +   n
  n   + (n-1) + ... +   2   +   1
----------------------------------
(n+1) + (n+1) + ... + (n+1) + (n+1) = n*(n+1)
```

Comment: +1 The sum of the first k integers is explained pretty well [here](http://www.9math.com/book/sum-first-n-natural-numbers), but you'll want to memorize it...

Comment: ah thanks, now i understand where the 1 comes from. so i guess if i understand correctly, the k*(k+1)/2 is just a regular arithmetic formula that i should "just know"...

Answer (score 1):

one way of working it out is:

sum=1+2+3+4+...+n

2*sum = 1+2+3+4+...+n + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 +...+n = 1+(n)  +  2+(n-1)  +  3+(n-2)..+ (n)+1

2*sum=1+n  + 1+n  + 1+n...

2*sum = n(1+n)

sum=n*(n+1)/2

but an easier way to see this is to imagine a square or a grid matrix.

as i goes down to each new row, j goes across and extra column to the diagonal of the matrix (as i<=j .. we know j can't get past the diagonal).
This means all the operations are a combination of (i,j) on one side of the matrix's diagonal.
The number of operations is therefore half the area of the entire matrix. if the matrix is a n*n matrix, then we have about n*n/2 area (but since we can't count the diagonal twice its actually n*(n-1)/2

Comment: Also, i'm not sure if you need to come up with this formula yourself.. it's a fairly standard formula. the sum 1+2+3+..+n comes up in many areas of mathematics. Most people just use it without proving it each time

Comment: thanks robert, the explanation of the square/matrix made it very easy for me to visualize

Answer (score 0):

OK, think like this:

```
When i = 1, inner loop runs (n - 1) times [j = 2 to n]
When i = 2, inner loop runs (n - 2) times [j = 3 to n]
When i = 3, inner loop runs (n - 3) times [j = 4 to n]
....
When i = k, inner loop runs (n - k) times [j = k + 1 to n]
...
When i = n - 1, inner loop runs (n - (n - 1)) = 1 time [j = n to n]
```

Now sum them up:

```
(n - 1) + (n - 2) + (n - 3) + ... + 1 = n(n - 1) / 2
```

In the worst case, the `exchange` will be done `n(n - 1) / 2` times.

Answer (score 0):

The series goes from (n-1) to (1) [(n-1), (n-2) ... (n-(n-1))]
check the sum of the series [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression) to know how it was derived. Its pretty easy to understand.

Comment: thx for the link, that made me realize it's just a formula that i should just know

Comment: But be careful cause that applies just for the arithmetic progression. In your case that would be the most applied but just a word of caution. :)